# Selenium and Chromedriver Issues with mac

Tags: macos, selenium, anaconda, selenium-chromedriver

I am relatively new to Python.  I have been using Jupyter Notebook for the most part but recently wanted to try running python scripts from my mac's terminal.  I am trying to run this following simple script:

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome()  
driver.get('http://www.google.com/');

driver.quit()
```

When I run this from Notebook, it works. But when I run it from my terminal I get the error "ImportError: No module named selenium". Why am I getting this error?

When I run "pip install selenium" from root, i get "Requirement already satisfied: selenium in /Users/FrankieD/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages".  Do I need to download this to another location on my mac?

Also, does my Chromedriver need to be stored in a particular location on my mac other than the project folder/path I am working in?

Thank You.

Comment: No. The only thing to make sure is that the terminal can access your anaconda installed modules or not?

Comment: @VivekKumar how can I verify that?

Comment: As i research this further, is it possible that because I have never downloaded Python to my mac, that it is defaulting to version 2.7.10 that came preinstalled and doesn't have selenium?                                                                                                    Frankies-MBP:/ root# which python
/usr/bin/python
Frankies-MBP:/ root# python --version
Python 2.7.10

Comment: Yes, check if you can execute python3 on terminal or not.

Comment: And if you just want to use terminal instead of notebook, you can use `/home/user/anaconda3/bin/python` and then run your script

Comment: I downloaded the latest version of Python and it worked. Thanks! @VivekKumar